# CS50 Web Programming - Postgres SQL error while importing books.csv file

Tags: python, database, postgresql, python-import, cs50

In my Postgres Database, I have made a `Table` books. Inside books, I have 5 columns - `id`, `title`, `author`, `isbn`, `year`.

I am running my import.py code as shown below to import the books.csv contents :-

```
import csv
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


def main():
    f = open("books.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
for isbn, title, author, year in reader:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author, year) VALUES (:isbn, :title, :author, :year)",
               {"isbn": isbn, "title": title, "author": author, "year": year})
    print(f"Added book with isbn {isbn}.")
db.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I try to import into my columns, I get following error while running python `import.py` on git bash:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "isbn"
LINE 1: ...RT INTO books (isbn, title, author, year) VALUES ('isbn', 't...

.. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author, year) VALUES (%(isbn)s, %(title)s, %(author)s, %(year)s)']
   [parameters: {'isbn': 'isbn', 'title': 'title', 'author': 'author', 'year': 'year'}] 
   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)
```

import.py is unable to talk to the table created. The table appears while checking for the table in psql. However, when I try to create a different table via command line in psql, it does not work.

```
                                                         ^
```

Comment: Downvote because of the pictures of text. What is wrong with cutting and pasting?

Comment: Added the error and removed the pictures.

Comment: Thanks very much @Aakash - that will make your question more useful to others. You'd be surprised how many people can end up referencing a question and the more searchable it is the more useful to everyone.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHuxton, I will keep in mind for future questions too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've either created the table in another database from the one you're connecting to with Python or you've called it something else

I'd check with the tool you created it with...

Comment: I have manually made my table and columns in pgAdmin4. I further used command line of psql to confirm that. I am still unable to import the data into my database. Is there another way you would recommend creating table? Somehow I couldn't make table via psql command line

Comment: Then you've either got your connection string wrong, or maybe you've created it in a schema that isn't in your search path

Comment: Found a solution. The postgres and python was not connected. I remade the tables using https://adminer.cs50.net/ and I was able to fill the columns with csv data